# items of the listview are not showing

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am creating a cutomized listView. the model of each item in the listView is as shown in the "model_view" layout.
I set the data to the adapter as shown in "set adapter" below.
the cutomized adapter is as shown in "CutomizedAdapter"

when i run the App, there are no items appearing on the screen

why the items of the listview are not showing

**model_view**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:text="Name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:text="Address: "/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvGender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:text="gender: "/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**set adapter**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    this.mModelList = new ArrayList<RowModel>();

    this.mModelList.add(new RowModel("xx", "Mümchen", "M"));
    this.mModelList.add(new RowModel("xx", "Karlsruhe", "M"));
    this.mModelList.add(new RowModel("xx", "Mümchen", "F"));
    this.mModelList.add(new RowModel("xx", "Karlsruhe", "F"));
    this.mModelList.add(new RowModel("xx", "Alexandria", "M"));
    this.mModelList.add(new RowModel("xx", "Cairo", "F"));

    CustomizedAdapter adapter = new CustomizedAdapter(this, R.layout.model_view, this.mModelList);
    this.mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**CutomizedAdapter**:

```
public class CustomizedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mCxt = null;
private int mRowModelLayout;
private ArrayList<RowModel> mRowsList = null;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public CustomizedAdapter(Context cxt, int rowModelLayout, ArrayList<RowModel> rowsList) {
    this.mCxt = cxt;
    this.mRowModelLayout = rowModelLayout;
    this.mRowsList = rowsList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvAddress;
    public TextView tvGender;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int pos = position;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    View rowView;

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_view, null);
    holder.tvName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    holder.tvAddress=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
    holder.tvGender=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGender);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(mCxt, "You Clicked "+mRowsList.get(pos).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you are not filling below methods?

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mRowsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mRowsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Also, you are not initializing your `inflater`

So, initialize it in your constructor like

```
public CustomizedAdapter(Context cxt, int rowModelLayout, ArrayList<RowModel> rowsList) {
    this.mCxt = cxt;
    this.mRowModelLayout = rowModelLayout;
    this.mRowsList = rowsList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: now the App crashes because "inflater" is not initialized...i am trying to initialize it as follows:inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); but the "getSystemService" cant be recognized

Comment: In your constructor it should be available like this `inflater = (LayoutInflater) cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 1):

Because you return the wrong thing in these methods:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

These functions do not return nothing, change it to:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mRowList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mRowList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position; //or mRowList.get(position).getID()
}
```

Comment: what is `position.getID()`?

Comment: now the App crashes because "inflater" is not initialized...i am trying to initialize it as follows:inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); but the "getSystemService" cant be recognized